# call function before scrolling to the bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know how to call a function when scrolling hits the bottom of the page.

```
$(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()
```

But I would like to do it a little bit before it hits the bottom. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
      alert('end of page');
   }
});
```

[check this example](http://jsfiddle.net/wQfMx/)

`-10` indicates how far away from end of page user must be before function executes. This gives you the flexibility to adjust the behavior as needed

Comment: Please always post your code in the question/answer. If jsfiddle goes down, or removes your link, this answer would be worthless.

Comment: Sorry for my inconvenience  yes you are absolutely right Rory McCrossan.

Comment: No worries, just FYI for future answers :)

Comment: This did not work for me in your example. All it did was call alert when I hit the bottom of the page. I would like to call a function BEFORE I reach the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there..
To check whether user is near the bottom you could decide on an offset after which you decide that user is near the bottom and is about to reach it.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - offset) {
       callFunction();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add "a little bit before" to the equation and check if you have already passed it for example:

```
var a_little_bit_before = 400;

if ( $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - a_little_bit_before ) {
    alert("TA DA!");
}
```